# Mask some part of String

Tags: java, regex, mask

I have phone no and email address. I dont want to show full information.
So I am thinking mask some character using Regex or MaskFormatter.

**Input and desired result**

```
1) 9843444556 -  98*******6   
2) test@mint.com - t***@****.com
```

I have achieved this with String loop. But exactly I want to this by using regex or mask. Would you please kindly inform it?

Comment: why would you want to do it with regex?  What is wrong with the loop?

Comment: @MK No just want to do from different way...

Comment: you have to justify why you want to do it the wrong way, otherwise we can't (shouldn't) help you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Phone:

```
String replaced = yourString.replaceAll("\\b(\\d{2})\\d+(\\d)", "$1*******$2");
```

Email:

```
String replaced = yourString.replaceAll("\\b(\\w)[^@]+@\\S+(\\.[^\\s.]+)", "$1***@****$2");
```

**Explanation: phone**

- The `\b` boundary helps check that we are the start of the digits (there are other ways to do this, but here this will do).
- `(\d{2})` captures two digits to Group 1 (the two first digits)
- `\d+` matches any number of digits
- `(\d)` captures the final digit to Group 2
- In the replacement, `$1` and `$2` contain the content matched by Groups 1 and 2

**Explanation: Email**

- The `\b` boundary helps check that we are the start of the characters (there are other ways to do this, but here this will do).
- `(\w)` captures one word char to Group 1
- `[^@]+` matches one or more chars that are not `@`
- `\S+` matches one or more chars that are not whitespace chars
- `(\.[^\s.]+)` captures a dot and any chars that are not a dot or space to Group 2
- In the replacement, `$1` and `$2` contain the content matched by Groups 1 and 2

Comment: @zx81, I want to mask string but using regex matcher is it possible?